How to retrieve data from excel to postgres DB using python?
enter image description here
This is an image of my excel template, I need to retrieve data from it and fill my postgres table as shown in the picture, and the table code is:
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    "Test_Id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "Test_Name" text NOT NULL,
    "Test_Code" text NULL,
    "Test_Description" text NOT NULL,
    "Test_Parent_Id" numeric NOT NULL,
    "Level_Test_Id" numeric NULL,
    "Level_Test_Name" text null
    
    CONSTRAINT "Test_Id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Test_Id")
);

The difference here is that the format of the excel table as showing above, is not matching with the table in the database.
for example:
"Test_Name"='TestA'
"Test_Name"='TestA indicator name A1.1'
"Test_Code"= 'A'
"Level_Test_Name" in ('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4','Level 5')

PS: 'TestA' is the parent test and 'TestA indicator name A1.1' is the child.
How to write a python code that could fill each column of the database table with the data in the excel file ?


How can Test_Name be both 'TestA' and 'TestA indicator name A1.1'? FYI, using mixed case is dooming you to a future of always double quoting the field names. Change to all lower case and make your life easier. 2) Update your question to show how TestA indicator name A1.1 broken down into the component fields.  3) Not sure why "Level_Test_Name" is necessary, as for example A1.1 and A5.1 already incorporate that.



'TestA' is the parent name and 'TestA indicator name A1.1' is the child name and both should be under the same column
"Level_Test_Name" is shown in which level the child is whether Level 1, Level 2...


A) If that is the case then you should have two tables: 1) One for the parent test. 2) One for the child tests with a Foreign Key relationship between the two. B) In any case everything you need to know can be parsed out of TestA indicator name A1.1.
